# php - Why inserting variable to html this way failed?

Tags: php, html, variables

I know inserting a php variable value into html have many ways : echoing, printing, etc. But, when I try to insert with equal sign method (demoed below), it just fails. I have seen it in many code, is it now deprecated?

As example I have this php code :

```
<?php
// Assign variable value
$nox = "Hello boy!"
?>
```

and then html code :

```
...
<div>
  <p>Why this one fail : <?php = $nox ?></p>
</div>
...
```

Why it is failed? Is it deprecated or It was me that did wrong in implementation.

In firelogger I got message.

> syntax error, unexpected '='

Comment: try using echo or print

Comment: I use them. The one I ask is related to the equal sign. Well, thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @Someone : What's that -1 ? I have search it on google as well as SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to assign a value to $nox by using the following syntax:

```
<?php = $nox ?>
```

This will result in a fatal error due to the fact that you are using the assignment operator (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) to perform a non-permitted action - no value can be assigned to $nox.

I believe what you mean to do is one of the following:

```
<?php print $nox ?>
```

or

```
<?= $nox ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing up two different syntaxes for printing content.

**Method 1**: use `echo`

```
<?php echo $nox ?>
```

This is the most common way to produce output and works in all versions of PHP and does not require special configuration.

**Method 2**: use short tags synatx `<?=`

```
<?= $nox ?>
```

This requires short tags being enabled and will not work otherwise. This is commonly used in templates/views to keep the PHP code to a minimum and reduce clutter. (As of [PHP 5.4 short tags does not need to be enabled to use this syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)).

Comment: Method 2 no longer requires short tags to be enabled since php 5.4,

Comment: @Anigel I was trying to find a link for that and started to think I was crazy

Comment: And now that I know what to look for I found it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this syntax:

```
<?= $nox ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have the `;` in every 
statement of code, that's a probability that you had that error. You should end every `php` statement with `;`.

Like This:

```
<?php
    // Assign variable value
    $nox = "Hello boy!";
?>
```

And print it properly with the use of `echo` like this:

```
...
<div>
    <p>Why this one fail : <?php echo $nox; ?></p>
</div>
...
```